# RPD by group google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to calculate the RPD (relative percent difference) for different groups in a google sheet.

[image: sheet with my data]

I can do it for the whole array but miss it when I add the groups. Works when I use it for percentrank though.....

For all values, works fine
`=(B20-AVERAGE($B$20:$B$30))/(AVERAGE($B$20:$B$30))*100`

Try A

`ArrayFormula((B20-AVERAGE($B$20:$B$30))/(AVERAGE(IFERROR(B$20:B$32*IF($A$20:$A$32=$A20,1,""),""),B20)))*100`

Try B

`=ARRAYFORMULA(B20-average(IFERROR(($B$20:$B$32)*IF($A$20:$A$32=$A20,1,""),B20)))/AVERAGE(B20:B34)*100`

[sheet as screenshot shows](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IN7_d3ANnN4jukuL24kdOw3zPx-XWfhb7R6a3oT4Igg/edit?usp=sharing)

Any idea?

Example of table, I made all values equal besides first one to see if the calculation is right. Expected result in the last column

| Group | Value | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PG | 40 | 18.92 |
| PG | 33 | -1.89 |
| SF | 40 | 18.92 |
| PG | 33 | -1.89 |
| SG | 40 | 18.92 |
| SG | 33 | -1.89 |
| PG | 33 | -1.89 |
| SF | 33 | -1.89 |
| SF | 33 | -1.89 |
| SF | 33 | -1.89 |
| SG | 33 | -1.89 |
| SG | 33 | -1.89 |

String in "Group" can be in any order so I need to find a way to handle this. In the final version I will have 25 columns I need to calculate according to "Group".

Comment: The first two desired results are `18.92` and `-1.89`. Please explain _why_ these results would be the correct results.

Comment: Copy of [Percentage difference to average in an array and contains string](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/201597798).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the difference of each value and its group's average, and divide the result by the group average, try this:

```
=lambda( 
  groupAverage, 
  to_percent((B2 - groupAverage) / groupAverage) 
)( 
  average(filter(B$2:B$14, A$2:A$14 = A2)) 
)
```

To evaluate the same through the whole column with an array formula, try this:

```
=lambda( 
  groups, values, 
  map( 
    groups, values, 
    lambda( 
      group, value, 
      lambda( 
        groupAverage, 
        if( 
          len(group), 
          to_percent((value - groupAverage) / groupAverage), 
          iferror(1/0) 
        ) 
      )( 
        iferror(average(filter(values, groups = group))) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)( 
  A2:A, B2:B 
)
```

To get the previous value in the same group on a row-by-row basis, try this:

```
=single( iferror( sort( filter( { B$1:B1, row(B$1:B1) }, A$1:A1 = A2 ), 2, false ), B2 ) )
```

To get the relative change to previous value in the same group, try this:

```
=to_percent( iferror((B2 - C2) / B2) )
```

See the [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IN7_d3ANnN4jukuL24kdOw3zPx-XWfhb7R6a3oT4Igg/edit#gid=364674044).

Comment: I edited the post. String of values can be in any order so I need to be able to handle this.

Comment: The formulas in the answer handle group names in any order. Please show your _manually entered_ expected results from the sample data in the table in the question.